# Java replaceAll Illegal repetition

Tags: java, parsing, replaceall

I have a big json stored in a string. I want to change some part of the String and I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
>   Illegal repetition near index 6
>       "date":{"nil":"true"}
>             ^
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:3104)
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2101)
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665)
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.(Pattern.java:1337)
>         at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)
>         at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2162)
>         at basari.process.MsisdnProcess.setAllPropTypes(MsisdnProcess.java:51)
>         at testClass.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:98)

My code:

```
String example =  "deviceInfo":{"deviceBrand":"NOKIA","imei":"11111111","deviceModel":"6300","date":{"nil":"true"}}

example.replaceAll( "\"date\":{\"nil\":\"true\"}", "\"date\":\"2014-08-14T10:00:00.000+02:00\"");
```

Comment: It would be nice to have answers explaining why the regex is invalid instead of just giving workarounds.

Comment: Worked with replace();

Comment: It should be noted that some other regex engines have absolutely no problem with `{"nil":"true"}`, as it doesn't contain any number they just don't see it as a quantifier. It' a... feature... of the java regex parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)), instead of `replaceAll` (which uses regex).

You get this exception because in regex, `{...}` is a quantifier.
For example:

- `{1,3}` = 1 to 3 times
- `{3,}` = 3 or more times
- `{3}` = exactly 3 times

Comment: While it's overloaded and OP might not notice, you should probably link to the [`(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) version of the method, instead of `(char, char)`, given that OP is using `String`s.

Comment: @ajp15243 Thanks, didn't see that mistake.

Answer (score 4):

As the exception indicates, it's trying to parse it as a Regex instead of plain text. If you just want to replace a certain string with another one, use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) instead of `replaceAll()`.

As to why you get this particular exception: the `{ }` characters have [a specific meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and are used to indicate a repitition (aka: the amount of times a certain regex appears). In an actual regex this is supposed to take an integer value which you don't provide in your string.

Answer (score 4):

the `{` and `}` symbols are meaningful in regex.. you have to escape them with additional backslashes.

Use :

```
example.replaceAll( "\"date\":\\{\"nil\":\"true\"\\}",
        "\"date\":\"2014-08-14T10:00:00.000+02:00\""));
```